# How do I Get Started Using Flex and Ecplise Without Using Flex Builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, eclipse, flex3

I am a ASP.NET web developer who wants to learn Flex and Actionscript.
I want to first learn how to develop web applications using Flex without having to pay for Flex Builder. From what I have researched so far there is a way to get Flex working with Eclipse and I did stumble upon this website: 
http://systems.tinuum.net/?p=52

I tried to download the components they used, but I am still not sure how to get Flex working.
Can somebody please point me to a step-by-step guide on how to get started using Flex in Eclipse?

So, far it looks like you download Eclipse 3.5 + Flex 3.5 SDK + various plug-ins listed, but I'm not sure what to do next.

I am very interested in learning how to develop Rich Internet Applications using Flex, and would be extremely grateful if someone could help me get started.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess I still would like to know how to get a Flex development up and running with Eclipse without using Flex/Flash Builder; the article http://systems.tinuum.net/?p=52 suggests that this can be done.

So, getting this to work would be really awesome!

Thanks.
Abe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a free eclipse based Flex plugin, so FlashDevelop would be the only free IDE (although this isn't eclipse based obviously). You could also try FDT Pure if you can get any cash together, the license is only about 70 euros and would have enough features to get started.

Comment: I downloaded FlashDevelop and the Flex SDK and was able to get a good development environment set up; for an open source program, FlashDevelop is actually really good. I get code auto-complete and I can compile the MXML, which is great!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you will be using [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[FlexBuilder 3](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flexbuilder3) has a 60-days trial , which should be enough for you to get started.

Comment: You're right. The 60-day trial is a good start for now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FlashDeveloper is good, or try the Flex Builder for some 60 days

Comment: Thanks. I did find a free plug-in for Visual Studio 2008, which was referenced http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9536/using-adobe-flex-in-visual-studio/

It's a plugin from Ensemble called Tofino (http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml) and it does seem to work pretty well; it's missing the design mode, but you can still compile Flex applications and it has IntelliSense support.

Comment: :O :) flex in VS2008 !!!, waaaw, you're my hero man, I couldn't even imagine this possibility